# translating pyTorch code to CNTK code

Tags: cntk

I need to re-write some code from pyTorch to CNTK.
I know CNTK and deep learning basics quite well.
Is it easy to relate pyTorch and CNTK?
Do I need to be aware of some special things?

I did translate TensorFlow and CNTK codes before, and I found it easy. 
But I know Tensorflow reasonably well ... but now I do not want to put effort in learning pyTorch.

Comment: please show effort.. at least in searching SO or other websites if something is posted previously on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to export your model to ONNX format from PyTorch. Then you can load it in CNTK. See [here](https://github.com/onnx/tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/PytorchOnnxExport.ipynb) for saving and [here](https://github.com/onnx/tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/CntkOnnxExport.ipynb) for loading. Note that this is still a very new effort and different toolkits have different degrees of support for ONNX.

Comment: Thanks for your links Nikos!

However, I'm looking to implement/research/play around with by own to create my own network in CNTK and trained model (based on some code in pyTorch, just for guidance). 

Anyway, it seems from various feedback that there is no such 1:1 correspondence between lines of PyTorch code and CNTK code (unless one spends again time in learning about PyTorch!). 

I feel it's just easier to implement my own stuff in CNTK :-)